# Is it possible to animate a non-SVG image on UI?

Tags: css, user-interface, animation, interactive, interaction

I'm  wondering if it's possible to animate non-SVG image - png, jpg, gif, or other-  on a website -hovering, clicking, etc ?

My guess is to create a sequence and trigger them on a wished event. 
I assume the non-SVG image aren't link to the DOM since they aren't coded in any way.

So it would be a question of timing I guess between the graphics-animation and the DOM animation's elements? The idea is that when an specific event triggers, an specific animation trigger. The tricks should be to paused or slow-motion the animation meanwhile the visitor take a decision, so:

I think an example worths 1000words, so [here an example](https://youtu.be/agx1_gE-fRY?t=52).

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: You can animate the *entire* image. But not parts of it. SVG animation is usually used because you can edit / animate specific parts of the image. Fading a png/jpg out can be done on any type of image.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have edited my post and provided an example of what I think about, here the link: https://youtu.be/agx1_gE-fRY?t=52

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad for SO, but this would, in theory be possible with WebGL. Look into Three.js